# Highstock get color of Candle in grouped data series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highstock / Highcharts. My series type is candlestick. The data is grouped per minute. Is there a way to get the color of a specific candle other than attempting to calculate it based on the grouped data itself?

Comment: Please post your code that you have tried

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best I can come up with is:

```
chartObj.series[0].groupedData[pointIndex].graphic.fill
```

See this fiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/puFGT/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatley it is not possible, because datagrouping combine all values, and set defualt color.